# Add attribute to an edgelist based on degree

Tags: r, igraph

I have the following edges from an igraph (g):

```
from    to
1   3
1   5
2   1
2   3
3   1
4   5
4   1
```

I used:

```
g<- make_empty_graph(n=5) %>%
    add_edges(c(1,3, 1,5, 2,1, 2,3, 3,1, 4,5, 4,1)) %>%
    set_edge_attr("color", value = "red")
    E(g)[[]]
plot(g)
```

I computed the indegree by

```
g_in <- degree(g, mode='in")
g_in
[1] 3 0 2 0 2
```

I want to create a dataframe combining g and g_in as follows:

```
from to in_degree
1   3   2
1   5   2
2   1   3
2   3   2
3   1   3
4   5   2
4   1   3
```

That is, combine in_degree of "to nodes" only.
How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
data$in_degree <- setNames(degree(g, mode = "in"), V(g))[data$to]
#   from to in_degree
# 1    1  3         2
# 2    1  5         2
# 3    2  1         3
# 4    2  3         2
# 5    3  1         3
# 6    4  5         2
# 7    4  1         3
```

where I first create a mapping from vertices to their in-degrees,

```
setNames(degree(g, mode = "in"), V(g))
# 1 2 3 4 5 
# 3 0 2 0 2
```

and then apply it to `data$to`.

Comment: i got the following error: 

data$in_degree <- setNames(degree(g, mode = "in"), V(g))[data$to] Error in data$to : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable

Comment: @Erwin, try now. If it still doesn't work, what are the values of `V(g)` like? Integers?

Comment: It didn't work. str() shows: 

str(V(g)) Class 'igraph.vs' atomic [1:5] 1 2 3 4 5 ..- attr(, "env")=<weakref> ..- attr(, "graph")= chr "b9768984-2abc-11e8-8000-010000000000"

Comment: @Erwin, do you have a `data.frame` named `data` with two columns `from` and `to`?

Comment: I can make one with:

g <- sample_pa(10)

g_df <- as_data_frame(g, what="edges").

Comment: @Erwin, then it works to me. I suspect that initially you had a matrix, not a data frame.

Comment: Great. It did, yes.